# How to run studio.sh without opening a shell (using Ubuntu)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, android-studio

I can run studio.sh from the shell and it opens just fine.  I can't run it by clicking on it.  It just pauses like it's loading and then does nothing.  Similarly, a desktop shortcut I created pauses and then does nothing.

History (in case it's relevant):
I unpacked Android Studio in ~/android

I ran studio.h from the shell.  It opened and downloaded the sdk to ~/Android and did some other setup.

I wanted to keep Android stuff in one folder in my home directory so I moved android-studio to ~/Android from ~/android.

I can run it in the shell using "./studio.sh" or even from my home folder using "Android/android-studio/studio.sh".

I rm'd ~/.android, ~/.AndroidStudio, and the entire android-studio folder.  I unpacked it again and tried again.  It did some setup again, but still only works from the shell.  It only works from the shell.

I don't think I had this problem in Linux Mint.  I think I did all the same things then - including deleting the folder and unpacking it a second time.

Edit: In case it's relevant, to run it from the folder, I clicked "open with.." "Run Program".  I believe this worked once before I moved it from the original folder.

Comment: did you `chmod +x` it?

Comment: I did the first time I unpacked it.  Looking at it the second time, it's already rwxr-xr-x.  Nonetheless, giving the comment a +1 because I did forget to check before and thought it was a good question.

Comment: Examine your `~/.xsession-errors`, it probably contains an error message which reveals what went wrong. (If you're not running X11, wherever your GUI logs errors.)

Comment: cat ~/.xsession-errors  
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.

Answer (score 2):

After you start `studio.sh` from terminal. Click `Configure` on Welcome window and there is option to `Create Desktop Entry`.

Answer (score 2):

After opening it using terminal, you can go to: Tools -> Create Desktop Entry... then close it and click on the icon to open

Answer (score 1):

find location where you stored **android-stdio/bin** folder `/opt/` or `/usr/local/` open android stdio folder right click there and open terminal use following command

```
sudo gedit android-studio.desktop
```

then write following line in this file

> Don't forgot to check your stdio path /opt/ or /usr/local/ And write proper path **Exec** AND **Icon**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Android Studio
Comment=Integerated Development Environment for Android
Exec=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
Icon=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

save file and hit command

```
desktop-file-install android-studio.desktop
```

now shortcut file is ready click copy and past on desktop

Answer (score 0):

First make the script executable:

```
chmod +x studio.sh
```

Now, write click on the file, and open with "Terminal".

Comment: Didn't work.  Also, there's no "open with terminal" option.  I had to "open with Run Program".  That worked once before, if I remember correctly, but not working for me now.